# numeric choice field:How to let the user set a value by incrementing/decrementing the displayed value

Tags: android

I have a range say,1-100 and i want the user to select a value from this range.Ofcourse showing this with a spinner will be awful.I want to use the functionality of date widget,where we can pick a date by pressing a +/- sign,the longer the press ,higher the iteration speed.
I found numberpicker.java that has the code the date widget uses to get this functionality, but do i have to paste that entire code to achieve this functionality!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on how to pull out NumberPicker; I've followed it myself: http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

Answer (score 0):

> I found numberpicker.java that has the
>   code the date widget uses to get this
>   functionality, but do i have to paste
>   that entire code to achieve this
>   functionality!

Unfortunately, yes, plus perhaps some resources as well (I have not looked at that code recently). I am not aware of anyone who has pulled that out to make a reusable component, and it is not a widget in the SDK.

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark...Now I am gonna create my own Widget :)